# Can't predict using loaded FrozenModel

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I copied the code from [tfjs-examples/mobilenet/](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/mobilenet) and try to run my own frozen model, the model was loaded, but producing error when I try to use `predict` method.

I'm using tfjs of version `0.14.2` and Google Chrome, version `71.0.3578.98`

I used the [mobilenet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/mobilenet) example shown in [tfjs-examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/mobilenet) repo and started the server by `yarn watch`.

Secondly, I loaded my own FrozenModel successfully.

But when I use the `predict` method of the loaded model with a input of correct shape, it shown the error below:

[image]

```
ERROR: 0:163: 'updates' :  left of '[' is not of type array, matrix, or vecto
```

[image]

I just slightly modified the original `index.js` in the [mobilenet example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/mobilenet) and the script look like this:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

const MODEL_URL = 'path_to_tensorflowjs_model.pb';
const WEIGHTS_URL = 'path_to_weights_manifest.json';

let gan;
const ganDemo = async () => {
  status('Loading model...');

  gan = await tf.loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
  gan.predict(tf.zeros([1, 3, 450, 300])).dispose(); # error here

  ...
```

I had made sure the model was loaded successfully, and the shape of the input is correct (I intentionally tried other shape, and if the shape is not correct, it will throw another error)

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the version of tfjs npm you are using? 
Can you try to use the latest version v1.0.0-alpha2 or v0.15.1?

There is a [bug fix](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter/pull/288) related to sparseToDense op.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I was using `v0.14.2`. 

I had tried both `v0.15.1` and `v1.0.0-alpha2` by specifying the javascript:

`
script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0-alpha2/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
`

But the error still occur, any other suggestions?

Comment: The error looks like a shape mismatch, but it is hard to tell what the cause is. If you can share the model, I might be able to debug it.

Comment: I uploaded the model and a simple web page/server and steps to reproduce the error at: https://github.com/leemengtaiwan/tfjs-debug . Because the model I'm trying to load is very big (600 MB), I made a simple HTTP server which allow you to repeat loading the model without using the internet bandwidth. I will be very appreciated that if you can take time to help debug this. If there is anything I can do to help you debug this, please tell me, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try to convert the model again with newly released converter pip (v1.0.1).
I believe one of the scale weights is converted to a [0] shaped tensor.
If there are still errors, please shared the newly converted model. thanks.

Comment: This is solved via https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1235. Many thanks to @Ping Yu!